# Sharing data across multiple Excel and multiple computers

Tags: excel, vba, redis

I would like to share data across multiple Excels on several computers on the same network. It needs to be fast (faster than reading data off of a hard drive).

I'm using it for distributed rate limiting, similarly described here:

https://callhub.io/blog/2014/02/03/distributed-rate-limiting-with-redis-and-celery/

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to access a Redis datastore from Excel or VBA.

Anybody have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: More details.  What is your definition of "fast"?  How are your "multiple" computers connected?  What do you mean by "multiple" ?  10? 1000?

Comment: I edited my post. Let's say several computers on the same network. Let's say faster than reading off of a hard drive (less than 1/10 of a second).

Comment: @JPN were you able to find a solution on how to access Redis Cache from VBA?  I am looking for the same need. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this:

http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/

It works well.